# How to read multiple specific lines from a txt file (python)

Tags: python-3.x

### The question:

I am trying to have my program read multiple, specific lines from a text file. I have gotten to the stage where I am able to get the program to read multiple lines but I have to add them together and when printed they have '[],[]' around them.

### Here is my current code:

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
one=1
while one==1:
    a = open("solution.txt","r").readlines()
    line = a[1].split()
    line2 = a[0].split()
    print(line+line2)
    one=0
    time.sleep(3)
exit()
```

### Side note

I understand that there are similar questions although they're all very complicated. I'd just like a simple answer. I am using Python 3.5 and am not a noob nor a proffessional. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read lines from a file you can use a for loop like so:

```
lines = []
for line in enumerate(open("solution.txt", "r")):
    lines.append(line)
```

This will create a tuple containing the line number (starting at zero) and the contents of that line, it will do this for every line in the file.
It will then add each line number and line tuple to a list called lines.

If you want specific lines (eg. line 5 or line 7) you can use another loop to go through the contents of lines.

```
targetlines = [5, 7]
for line in lines:
    if line[0] in targetlines:
        print(line[1])
```

This will print the contents of line 5 and 7, on separate lines.
Note that they will still have the newline character on the end of them and so you may need to print it with `.rstrip()` which will remove the newline character.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and Inform you as to if it works for my situation.